# Python ElementTree get previous attrib with a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

I'm working with XML files. My file is like that :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''
<root>
    <a name='name1' label='label1'
      <b>
        <result para='1'
      </b>
    </a>
    <a name='name2' label='label2'
      <b>
        <result para='2'
      </b>
    </a>
    <a name='name3' label='label3'
      <b>
        <result para='3'
      </b>
    </a>
</root>
'''

myroot = ET.fromstring(xml)
```

I want to print the label from the `a` if the para from the `b` is equal to 1.
I have this code :

```
for type_tag in myroot.findall('.//result'):
    if type_tag.attrib['para'] == '1':
```

But I don't know how to go back to `a` to print the label.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ok @mkrieger1 thank you, thanks to your help I managed to solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as suggested, i took the problem backwards and solved it like this:

```
for type_tag in myroot.findall('a'):
    lab = type_tag.attrib['label']
    for e in type_tag.findall('./b/result'):
        if e.attrib['para'] == '1':
            print(lab)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another, shorter, way of doing it is using xpath:

```
for type_tag in myroot.findall('.*//result[@para="1"]/../..'):
    print(type_tag.attrib['label'])
```

Having said that, ET supports only a limited subset of xpath. So if you have more complex xml to deal with and have access to lxml, you should try to use that.